# create different buttons in the runtime using actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to create a number of buttons in the run time, each button has its own behavior like the style and the functionality
what function shoud i use to give instance name to the button?
as when i trace the name target it generated randomly as instance2 , instance6 and so on 
thank you

here is what i tried i create a class called glosbtn

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

for(var i:int=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(var j:int=0;j<6;j++)
{
var btn:glosbtn= new glosbtn();
addChild(btn);
btn.x=50*j;
btn.y=50*i;
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,glosbtnclick)

}
}

function glosbtnclick(e:Event){
    trace(e.target.name)
    // do my stuff
}
```

Comment: Just `btn.name = 'the_name_of_the_button';` ...

Comment: it didn't worked with me 
it keeps generate a random instance name 
but thanks i'll try it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As akmozo said in the comment, you can assign a `name` in your code:

```
var btn:glosbtn = new glosbtn();
btn.name = "button" + i + "_" + j;

function glosbtnclick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(e.currentTarget.name); // "button0_5", "button3_1", etc
}
```

That said, I can't think of many reasons you would really want to do this. Giving a display object a `name` is *not* the same as giving a symbol an "instance name" in the timeline. When you give a symbol an "instance name" in the timeline it also assigns a property on the parent timeline by that name, for example `mc.button1_2`, and it assigns the instance to that property when a timeline keyframe places it, and nulls the property when a keyframe removes it. None of that is true when you assign a display object `name`.

Instead, you usually keep track of your display objects with arrays or dictionaries. For example, you can use a 2d array to represent your grid of buttons, and use a dictionary to store some custom data related to it:

```
var buttons:Array = [];
var buttonsData:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    buttons[i] = [];
    for (var j:int = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        var btn:glosbtn = new glosbtn();
        addChild(btn);
        btn.x = 50 * j;
        btn.y = 50 * i;
        buttons[i][j] = btn;
        buttonsData[btn] = {i: i, j: j};
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, glosbtnclick);
    }
}

function glosbtnclick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // to look up button data
    var data = buttonsData[e.currentTarget] // {i: 0, j: 5}, {i: 3, j: 1}, etc
}

// to look up a button
var btn:glosbtn = buttons[0][3];
```

Comment: really thanks i'll try it 

the reason that i use this way is to define just one class and generate buttons from it in any page i want in my project
so if i had a 26 button it's better to generate them by a for loop rather than draw a 26 button manually

and cause i'm new to the AS i face many problems in it 

really thanks ^^